# Stack Overflow Error Within Code

Tags: recursion

This set of code is producing a stack overflow error due to infinite recursion (at least, I think it is). I have been staring at this code for a long time and can't figure out where the error happens to be. If anyone can help point out why I am getting such an error, that would be great.

```
public void DrawValues(Graphics g, Graphics2D g2, int x, int y, int a, int b){
        if (b>8){
            b = 0;
            a++;
            x = 61;
            y+=66;
        }
        if (a==8 && b==8){
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(Solver.Rows[a][b]), x, y);
        }
        else{
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(Solver.Rows[a][b]), x, y);
            DrawValues(g,g2, x+66, y, a, b++);
        }
    }
```

It will probably help to state that Rows is a 9x9 2D Array, a and b start at 0

Comment: You do not change `b` anywhere in your code and you need `b` to be equal `8` for your code to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using post-increment(b++) instead of pre-increment(++b) when you make recursive calling of `DrawValues` method. If you use post-increment, argument will be increment **after** method has been invoked. Hence, in your case, variable `b` never will be changed.

So, you should to use pre-increment:

```
...
DrawValues(g,g2, x+66, y, a, ++b);
...
```